# cmake: ordering of shared and static libraries important?

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake

I am creating a binary and linking in dependencies.

All binaries will link against `libpthread.so`
Release mode binaries will link against `libtcmalloc.a`

I have found that the ordering of libraries is important.

If I specify the call to `target_link_libraries` as follows, the binary fails to link.

```
target_link_libraries(
    ${NAME} 
         ${LIBS} pthread 
    optimized
         tcmalloc_minimal.a)
```

**Error:**

> ```
> [ 59%] Linking CXX executable app
> .../libtcmalloc_minimal.a(libtcmalloc_minimal_internal_la-static_vars.o): 
> In function `SetupAtForkLocksHandler':
>     /tmp/gperftools-2.4/src/static_vars.cc:119: 
> undefined reference to `pthread_atfork'
>
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
> ```

If, however, I change the ordering of libraries so that `pthread` appears **after** `tcmalloc`, then link works fine:

```
target_link_libraries(
    ${NAME} 
         ${LIBS} 
    optimized
         tcmalloc_minimal.a
    general
         pthread)
```

**Question:**

- Is there a way for cmake to work out the dependencies and create the correct link order automatically?
- gcc has `-Wl,--start-group` / `-Wl,--end-group` which solves this problem. Is there a way to make cmake use this feature?

Comment: Can't offer much specific advice, but your observation is expected: the ordering is usually important, as TUs/libraries are evaluated from left-to-right, undefined references recorded, and subsequent units searched for the undefined references. So, dependents should come first (leftmost), then the things on which they depend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the start-group & end-group in cmake as well:

```
target_link_libraries(${NAME} -Wl, --start-group 
  ${LIBS} optimized tcmalloc_minimal.a general pthread 
  -Wl, --end-group)
```

**Note**: This is an expensive operation though, so ideally you should figure out the circular dependencies and order them correctly. If thats not always possible, use the start & end group on the smallest possible subset of linked libraries.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer to your question is: Yes. Link order matters.

Slightly longer answer; depending on your tool-chain it matters more or less. Some linkers will only search later listed libraries for symbols they have already seen and won't search for an unknown symbol encountered in a library in libraries listed earlier (although some will).
So it all depends on your tools. But regardless of your tools in question, if you always take care to lists depending libraries before the ones they depend on, then you will be linking happily with any tool-chain (as long as you don't have circular dependencies that is - a few tools can deal with that but most can't).